# Is there any difference between if(!n/10)return; and if(n/10==0)return;?

Tags: c

Can anyone help me?
Is there any difference between

```
if (!n / 10)
    return;
```

and

```
if (n / 10 == 0) 
   return;
```

Comment: What is this even supposed to do? Why not just use `if(abs(n) < 10)`?

Comment: @paul Consider `if(abs(INT_MIN) < 10)` vs `(n / 10 == 0)`.  The 2nd is well defined.

Comment: @chux I'm not sure that extreme edge case is worth essentially obfuscating the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the two statements are different. `!n / 10` is equivalent to `(!n) / 10` and `n / 10 == 0` is equivalent to `!(n / 10)`.
Operator `!` has higher precedence than that of `/` operator and therefore `n` will bind to `!` first in `!n / 10`.

As @[Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) pointed in his comment, `!n` will evaluated either to `0` or `1` so, the expression will always be `false`.

Comment: And `(!n)` is either 0 or 1 after arithmetic conversions, so the expression is always false.

Answer (score 3):

This statement

```
if (!n / 10)
    return;
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( !n ) / 10)
    return;
```

According to the description of the operatpr (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
>   its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
>   equivalent to (0==E).

Thus if n is equal to 0 then expression `( !n ) / 10` equal to expression `1 / 10` and as the both operands are integers then the result is equal to 0.

If n is not equal to 0 then expression `( !n ) / 10` equal to `0 / 10` and its result again equal equal to 0.

So the original expression is equivalent to

```
if ( 0 ) return;
```

It means that the return statement will be executed never.

As for the second statement

```
if (n / 10 == 0) 
   return;
```

when n is less than 10 then  result of `n / 10` (provided that n is integer) will be equal to 0 and you will get

```
if ( 0 == 0 ) return;
```

So the return statement in the second if statement will be executed when `n` is less than `10`.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking this because maybe you are not clear about how if statement works. So, let me explain it first.
The syntax of if statement is
 if( expression )
{ procedure to follow }

Here expression to be used should be a logical one that it should result in true or false. Whenever the expression will result in true, the if statement is executed and vice-versa.
Another concept is that if the expression will result in 0 (false), the if statement will not get executed. 
Now when you use  if( n/10 ) , for n = 123, n/10 will result in 12 (the statement uses integers hence the result). Since it is not 0, it is treated as a true and the if statement will execute and n will be returned according to your code. Now n/10 doesn't change n, hence n(=123) will be returned and printed.
Now let's see about  if( n/10 == 0 ) . For the first time when n=123 is n/10 will be 12 which is not equal to 0. So, here a false is generated and the if statement is not executed unlike the previous one.
According to your desired logic you should use if( n/10==0 ).